# flyingsaucer/itext - is it possible to have table header on each PDF page

Tags: java, css, itext, flying-saucer

I have an HTML file which converted into PDF file with 5+ pages (a4 size)
almost all pages it's a big table which created using DIVs
the problem is that the table header is present only on the first page, but I want to have it on each page where the table present.

Is there any way how to add repeating table header on each page?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `table`, you can use the following CSS style, which will repeat `thead` on each page.

```
table {
    -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

If you're using `div`s, you can use page headers to repeat some content on each page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @page {  @top-center {content: element(header);}  }
        #header {position: running(header);}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">Header</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the approach with table, but obtain another problem, for the majority of pages headers create correct, but for some pages, I see the piece of extra space at the top of the page but no header created, and looks like this is floating-issue which related page content or row ( <tr>) content

Comment: @Roman I don't see what can cause this problem. Can you provide an example of HTML?